# Casting the Interface in Spring

Tags: java, spring

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //load the spring container
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    //retrieve beans from spring container
     Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach",Coach.class);
    //call methods on beans

     System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());

     context.close();
}
```

In the above code Coach is the interface and class is the same one declared in  the bean in Config file.

Please explain me how the casting is done for the Interface behind the scenes by Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will give example in detailed by steps -

Created an `interface` class **Person**

```
public interface Person {

     public void setPersonName(String personName);
     public String getPersonName();

     public void setPersonAge(Integer personAge);
     public Integer getPersonAge();
}
```

Created a **User** `class` which implements the **Person** `interface`

```
public class User implements Person {

    private String personName;
    private Integer personAge;

    @Override
    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersonName() {
        return this.personName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPersonAge(Integer personAge) {
        this.personAge = personAge;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getPersonAge() {
        return this.personAge;
    }
}
```

Created a `spring-bean.xml` file for `spring bean configuration`

```
<bean id="user" class="com.practice.User">
    <property name="personName" value="Michael"/>
    <property name="personAge" value="29"/>
</bean>
```

**MainApp** class to get the result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans.xml");

    //Spring Container will put the values to User Object, and 
    //here context.getBean("user") will get casted to Person interface
    Person person = (Person)context.getBean("user");

    System.out.println("name of person is : " + person.getPersonName() + 
                    "\nage of person is : " + person.getPersonAge());
    context.close();
}
```

hope this will help you, thanks.